# Jquery menu highlight items with slider parallax

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, highlight

I'm working on a parallax slider. On this parallax slider I added a jquery menu which highlight items when it selected. It works (take a look at : http://jsfiddle.net/jarod51/26Vgw/3/ )
but when I'm adding the Jquery script to go to the page slide, the highlight menu doesn't work anymore. Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem ?

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class='active'><a id="testSlide1" href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="testSlide2" href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="testSlide3" href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="testSlide4" href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
            <div class="da-slide">
                <h2>Warm welcome</h2>
                <p>When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane.</p>
                <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>
                <div class="da-img"><img src="images/1.png" alt="image01" /></div>
            </div>
<div class="da-slide">
                <h2>Easy management</h2>
                <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>
                <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>
                <div class="da-img"><img src="images/2.png" alt="image01" /></div>
            </div>
            <nav class="da-arrows">
                <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
            </nav>
</div>
</div>
<script>
// When we click on the LI
$("li").click(function(){
  // If this isn't already active
  if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
    // Remove the class from anything that is active
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    // And make this active
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
</script>
</script>   
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                var $slider = $('#da-slider');

                // initialize the slider
                $slider.cslider();

                // example how to go to page 1 when clicking on a link
                $('#testSlide1').on( 'click', function( event ) {

                    $('#da-slider').cslider( 'page', 0 );
                    return false;

                } );

                $('#testSlide2').on( 'click', function( event ) {

                    $('#da-slider').cslider( 'page', 1 );
                    return false;

                } );


            });
        </script>
```

Comment: This is all just assumptions but it may be that the slider js unbinds the click event, try putting your script after or does something similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/26Vgw/4/. If that's the case you may want to add the click event to `a` instead of `li`http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/26Vgw/5/. (Also open your console and check for errors, usually F12)

Comment: Thx so much Spokey for your help. It seems working now. I just have a warning (event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.). But all work fine ;). My next step, is to manage to highlight menu when clicking on arrows navigation. Do you think it is possible ?

Comment: Pretty sure that's possible, yeah :)